# fscanf not reading from a file containing asterisk characters

Tags: c, scanf

I tried to read a file containing an empty box of '*', the error message doesn't get printed, so the file is opened, but the scan doesn't work. I tried to print the count variable, and the value of count is 0. I don't really know where the fault is. Please help... Thanks

[the file content that I want to read](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgbpI.png)

```
int openmap(int file_no){
char filename[32];
char mapp[100][100];
int number;
int count;
int x[100];
int nomor = 1;



for(int i = 1; i <= file_no; i++){
        sprintf(filename, "map%d.txt", i);
        FILE *test = fopen(filename,"r");
        if(test)
        {
            printf("%2d. Map %d\n", nomor, i);
            x[nomor-1] = i;
            nomor++;
            fclose(test);

        }else if(!test && i > file_no){
            printf("No map available!");
            return 1;
        }

    }

do{
    printf("[0 to cancel] [1 - %d]>> ", nomor-1);
    scanf("%d", &number);
}while(number < 0 || number > file_no);


if(number > 0){
    sprintf(filename,"map%d.txt", x[number-1]);
    printf("%s", filename);
    FILE *open = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!open){
        printf("error");
    }

    while(!feof){
        fscanf(open, "%[^\n]\n", mapp[count]); 
        count++;
    }
    fclose(open);

    for(int i = 0; i < count ; i++){
    printf("%s\n", mapp[i]);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: How is `mapp` defined, and what is `count`'s initial value (is it set to zero)?

Comment: sorry for minimal information provided, the map is defined as `map[100][100]` and `count`'s initial value is 0

Comment: You shouldn’t check for feof until you have actually tried to read from the file.

Comment: Where is feof set?

Comment: Using `while (!feof(fp))` is always wrong.  Using just `while (!feof))` checks whether the function pointer for `feof` is null (it isn’t!) which is even less helpful.

Comment: Also, don't name the variable containing the file pointer "`open`", since this shadows an existing function named `open()`. In general, avoid using verbs for variable names.

Comment: @G.Sliepen `open()` is not in the standard C library - so OP may not be shadowing it.  `open()` is common in other libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I created a small test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main () {
    char mapp[100][100];
    int i, count = 0;
    char filename[32];

    sprintf(filename, "test.txt");
    FILE *open = fopen(filename, "r");
    if(!open){
        printf("error");
    }

    while(!feof(open)){
        fscanf(open, "%[^\n]\n", mapp[count]); 
        count++;
    }
    fclose(open);

    for(i = 0; i < count ; i++){
        printf("%s\n", mapp[i]);
    }
}
```

as far as i can see the only issue you have regarding the relevant section is your `while` loop condition, you should use: `while(!feof(open))` - i tested my solution and it works so it seems that this is the only issue in your solution